# Archiving all the done states

Tags: elisp, org-mode

I want to archive all the DONE todo states in a file, The below code extends the function specified in the link (please look at the comment in the link to see why the answer provided does not work)
[How to archive all the DONE tasks using a single command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997387/how-to-archive-all-the-done-tasks-using-a-single-command)
 as below

```
(defun my-org-archive-subtree ()
  (if (string-match "^\*.* DONE" (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol)))
  (setq org-map-continue-from (point-at-bol))
  (setq org-map-continue-from nil))

(org-archive-subtree))

(defun my-org-archive-done-tasks ()
  (interactive)
  (org-map-entries 'my-org-archive-subtree "/DONE" (list "/home/myhome/org/office.org")))
```

which seems to get in to infinite loop for the below contents in the file 
office.org while execting the s2 heading

* s1

** DONE ss1

* s2

** NEXT ss2

** sss3

Why does it goes in to infinite loop and how to solve the problem.

**Update:-**
    This was due to the bug in the org-scan-tags function which was called by
org-map-entries fn. The bug has been reported and fixed. To view the discussions
on the mailing list click [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2011-12/msg00464.html)

Comment: I looked into this a little. I used [this code](https://gist.github.com/1981472) and the problem seems to happen after the work has been done (in my example) in the 2nd call to org-archive-subtree. I couldn't debug any further than that because of some wierd edebug error. I'll try and find it for you though.

Comment: @nicferrier thanks for being generous. Actually i have found the bug and reported and it's been fixed(http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2011-12/msg00464.html). I forgot to update about this.

Comment: Please, write your update as an answer and accept it. So the question is marked as answered in the overview.