# When archiving done task in org-mode can they still contribute to the overall % completed?

Tags: org-mode

I just started to work with org-mode and I really like it. I've come across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997387/how-to-archive-all-the-done-tasks-using-a-single-command/27043756) how to archive the done task in a more automated way. My question is now: Once the done tasks are move to another archive-file do they still contribute to the % completed? Is there a way to make them still contributing to the overall status? Otherwise, as there won't be any done task the completion status will always be 0.

Comment: Instead of moving the task to the archive file you could set the archive tag with C-c C-x a (org-toggle-archive-tag). Not sure if this still counts then.