# How to archive all the DONE/DELEGATED/DEFERRED tasks using a single command

Tags: org-mode

This is a follow up question on [How to archive all the DONE tasks using a single command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997387/how-to-archive-all-the-done-tasks-using-a-single-command).

The solution given by Stefan works well for single DONE statement. How can it be extended to work with multiple DONE statements?

Stefan gave the following solution:

```
(defun org-archive-done-tasks ()
  (interactive)
  (org-map-entries
    (lambda ()
      (org-archive-subtree)
      (setq org-map-continue-from (org-element-property :begin (org-element-at-point))))
   "/DONE" 'tree))
```

I have the following org-todo-keywords:

```
(setq org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence "TODO(t)" "NEXT(n)" "WAITING(w)" "PROJECT(p)" "|" "DONE(d)" "DELEGATED" "DEFERRED")))
```

The goals is to archive all the tasks marked DONE, DELEGATED or DEFERRED. I have tried to use the matching as explained [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html), but have not been able to get it working. I tried for example:

```
MATCH = "/DONE|/DELEGATED|/DEFERRED"
```

I am new to elisp, a solution with explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is a bit obscure, but if I read the page that you linked to correctly, I think (untested!) that the following will work:

```
"/+DONE|+DELEGATED|+DEFERRED"
```

That's very similar to the last example on that page: select entries with a TODO property (/) <s>that is not empty (!) and</s> with a value of that TODO property that is DONE or DELEGATED or DEFERRED.